# Bad formatting of arabic text when mixed with 1%

Tags: unicode, arabic, right-to-left, bidi

here is the code

```
<code>
     <source> %1 added %2 to the group </source>
     <translation type="unfinished"> 1% أضاف %2 للمجموعة</translation>
</code>
```

Problem is that i want the text to be reversed in translation, so instead of "1% أضاف %2 للمجموعة", i want to have: [للمجموعة ("percent" 2) أضاف("percent" 1)]

For some reason even notepad doesn't allow you to put %1 at the far right of an Arabic sentence because Arabic is right to left, so maybe you can't start a sentence with %1.

Are there any workarounds for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to force the writing direction for the numbers and the percentage symbol. All of them are left-to-right characters. This is because the beginning of your string "1%" is written on the left. After that, the Arabic letters are all right-to-left, while the "2%" is left-to-right again, but immediately returns to arabic right-to-left. So the output is perfect correct.

To achieve what you intend, you have to force the right-to-left writing direction at the beginning of your string. Add a RTL character (&rlm; or U+200F in Unicode) before the first position start of your string and it displays as follows:

```
‏1% أضاف %2 للمجموعة
```

Inserting more RTL characters at the crucial positions (directly before the numbers and percentages), you can make it look like this:

```
‏1‏% أضاف ‏%2 للمجموعة
```